# How can i highlight line when user hovers over it in wpf?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Currently users can draw on the canvas by clicking and dragging their mouse. How can I change the color of the line to indicate the user's cursor is hovering over the line? It would be ideal to make it highlight when the cursor is within 5 pixels of any given line to indicate they are close.

**Inital drawing...**

[image]

**When user's cursor is either hovering directly over or within 5 pixels of any given line.**

[image]

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas  Name="paintSurface" MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown_1" MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove_1" >
            <Canvas.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="White" Opacity="0"/>
            </Canvas.Background>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.cs**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Point currentPoint = new Point();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Canvas_MouseDown_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ButtonState == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
                currentPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
        }

        private void Canvas_MouseMove_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                Line line = new Line();

                line.Stroke = SystemColors.WindowFrameBrush;
                line.X1 = currentPoint.X;
                line.Y1 = currentPoint.Y;
                line.X2 = e.GetPosition(this).X;
                line.Y2 = e.GetPosition(this).Y;

                currentPoint = e.GetPosition(this);

                paintSurface.Children.Add(line);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What if it's hovering within 5 pixels of two or more lines?

Comment: Also, you do realize that you're adding a segment of line every time mouse moves?  So, you don't have two children added in that code, you actually have  a lot more than that.  You should solve that issue first.

Comment: It's likely the best option for you would be to put down an invisible hitbox(Transparent ellipse comes to mind) in a ZOrder higher than your lines when you draw them and execute a MouseEnter and MouseLeave. This will probably require that you create a custom sub-class that keeps track of all the lines(And hit boxes) drawn when you have the mouse button held down so that you can reference the entire line itself as your mouse move function currently draws lines that are roughly 1 pixel in size per drawing. BTW this will be pretty RAM expensive...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Note:**  There are two versions of the sample program here, new and old.  Take a look at both to get an idea of what you can do.

Here's a sample application that fixes the issue you were unaware of, which is the fact that you drew numerous lines with one stroke and not a single line.  You should use a Polyline.  If you use Visual Studio 2015, then there's a Live Visual Tree, which will show you exactly what I mean; otherwise, you can use a tool such as Snoop to see the same thing. It also addresses you original question, which is the highlighting.

The new version is the first code portion that is shown here.  It uses a dictionary to link base line and highlight lines, so that you may get to the underlying base line if need to (such as when you want to delete it).  It also highlights the base, versus the highlighting the highlight line, which is what the old version did.  The highlight line is simply used for the selection zone buffer.  Increase or decrease its stroke to get the desired selection buffer (you mentioned 5 pixels in your post).

**Preview:**

[image]

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Canvas Name="paintSurface" Background="White" MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown" 
            MouseUp="Canvas_MouseUp" MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove"/>
</Window>
```

**C#:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Polyline _baseLine;
        Polyline _highlightLine;
        Point _currentPoint;
        bool _newLine;

        Dictionary<Polyline, Polyline> _lines = new Dictionary<Polyline, Polyline>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _newLine = true;
        }

        private void Canvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_highlightLine != null  && !_newline)
            {
                _highlightLine.MouseEnter += ShowHighlight;
                _highlightLine.MouseLeave += HideHighlight;
            }
        }

        private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                if (_newLine)
                {
                    _baseLine = new Polyline
                    {
                        Stroke = SystemColors.WindowFrameBrush,
                        StrokeThickness = 1.0
                    };
                    _highlightLine = new Polyline
                    {
                        Opacity = 0.0,
                        Stroke = SystemColors.WindowFrameBrush,
                        StrokeThickness = 10.0
                    };

                    paintSurface.Children.Add(_baseLine);
                    paintSurface.Children.Add(_highlightLine);
                    _lines.Add(_highlightLine, _baseLine);
                    _newLine = false;
                }

                _currentPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
                _baseLine.Points.Add(_currentPoint);
                _highlightLine.Points.Add(_currentPoint);
            }
        }

        private void ShowHighlight(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var line = sender as Polyline;
            if (line != null)
            {
                _lines[line].Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LimeGreen);
            }
        }

        private void HideHighlight(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var line = sender as Polyline;
            if (line != null)
            {
                _lines[line].Stroke = SystemColors.WindowFrameBrush;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll notice the _newLine flag boolean.  I use it to indicate whether a new Polyline should be drawn.  When the mouse is down, that's an indicator that a new line needs to be created.  I don't hook up the MouseEnter and MouseLeave handles for the line until the mouse is up because I don't want highlighting to be distracting during the drawing process of the line.  You have to give some sort of stroke to the _highlightLine and then set its opacity to 0 to make it invisible, but still respond to hit tests; otherwise, MouseEnter and MouseLeave handlers will never get invoked.

**OLD (The old version of the program.  Still a good one to check out.):**

What I do here is add a highlighting polyline on top of the base one and set its stroke to be 10 instead of the base's 1.  You can adjust that stroke thickness to get yourself the desired selection "buffer" zone. I literally spent about 10-15 minutes on this, so there could be ways to improve it, but this should give you a solid base to build upon.  If you wish to perform some actions down the road on these lines you're highlighting, such being able to delete them, then I suggest adding both the _baseLine and the _highlightLine to a dictionary, where _highlightLine is the key and _baseLine is the value.  That way, when you select the _highlightLine, you may access the underlying _baseLine.

**Preview:**

[image]

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Canvas Name="paintSurface" Background="White" MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown" 
            MouseUp="Canvas_MouseUp" MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove"/>
</Window>
```

**C#:**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Polyline _baseLine;
        Polyline _highlightLine;
        Point _currentPoint;
        bool _newLine;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _newLine = true;
        }

        private void Canvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_highlightLine != null && !_newline)
            {
                _highlightLine.MouseEnter += ShowHighlight;
                _highlightLine.MouseLeave += HideHighlight;
            }
        }

        private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                if (_newLine)
                {
                    _baseLine = new Polyline
                    {
                        Stroke = SystemColors.WindowFrameBrush,
                        StrokeThickness = 1.0
                    };
                    _highlightLine = new Polyline
                    {
                        Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green),
                        Opacity = 0.0,
                        StrokeThickness = 10.0
                    };

                    paintSurface.Children.Add(_baseLine);
                    paintSurface.Children.Add(_highlightLine);
                    _newLine = false;
                }

                _currentPoint = e.GetPosition(this);
                _baseLine.Points.Add(_currentPoint);
                _highlightLine.Points.Add(_currentPoint);
            }
        }

        private void ShowHighlight(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var line = sender as Polyline;
            if (line != null)
            {
                line.Opacity = 1.0;
            }
        }

        private void HideHighlight(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var line = sender as Polyline;
            if (line != null)
            {
                line.Opacity = 0.0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Additional Thoughts:**

If you want to go full XAML as far as styling, you've got a few options.  First option is to create a style that highlights TargetType Polyline on IsMouseOver property being true; however, you won't get the 5 pixel buffer with this one.  To accomplish that 5 pixel buffer, you'd need to create a custom template, which requires more work than what I've demonstrated here.  Of course... if you're feeling very adventurous, there's always the option of deriving from Shape and create yourself a highlightable/selectable Polyline -- it's just a lot of work, compared to the above code.  The bright side is that it'll be reusable.  It just depends on your situation, needs and wants.

Comment: @AbinMathew Not all of it. You may create a style for the base line and a style for the highlight line, but then you'd still have to apply that style in code to the lines that are created and added to the canvas, which is just as much work if not more. Then you'd have to worry about figuring out how to handle the selection area and if you choose to go with a box or an overlay line like I did here, there's the problem of linking them -- you'd have to have a custom template or element. There are many ways of accomplishing things in WPF if you're willing to put in the effort.

Comment: you got it right, as i saw the question, i thought of doing it in XAML. my worry was how to avoid mouse events as some time framework matters.

Comment: Wow you nailed this one on the head B.K. thank you so much for the explanation and break down. I appreciate it very much. This a a huge help for me and anyone reading this post. Great stuff.

Comment: @JokerMartini No problem.

Comment: @B.K. do you do any freelance WPF work? If so send me an email at jokermartini@gmail.com I'd love to see if you could help me out with something.

Comment: @JokerMartini  I never have, but I develop fulltime.  I'll shoot you an email and we'll see if we're a match.